# Reference design for a HSK machine spindle?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, machine-design, standards

Is there a reference design somewhere on the web for a HSK milling machine spindle *(mainly HSK type A, between 40-63)*? I'm mainly looking at the fixating mechanism (drawbar et al) and its tolerances; I'm planning to retrofit one on my manual machine.

I've seen the DIN papers but they don't seem to reference the internals - and I'm not paying to find out the hard way. (Unless someone here owns it and can confirm that these details are present?)

Comment: which hsk milling spindle? surely there is more than one...

Comment: Edited the question adding the pertinent info. Sorry about that, and thanks for pointing it out to me.

Comment: https://tacrockford.com/technical/machine-tool-taper-identification/hsk-taper-information/hsk-a25-to-63-tool-holder-blanks/part/619.563.063.100/#image

Maybe this'll get you further, but i'm not exactly sure which dimensions you specifically need/want, maybe upload a drawing labeling those you require?. I don't have any hsk's laying around from 25-63 unfortunately.

Comment: http://www.atcogmbh.com/site/thdevices/techinfo/hsk_clampings_manual/hsk_standard.pdf

or this

Comment: I'm mostly looking for the dimensions for the inside of the spindle, how the holder is fixated by the "mandrel", as it seems to be called. Funny thing with HSK, it is supposed to be non-proprietary, but it's much harder to find accurate info for it than its more established counterparts.....